# Op amp with potentiometer

Tags: circuit-analysis, operational-amplifier

I have to find voltage gain $$\frac{v_2}{v_1}$$ as a function of x in the following circuit:

[image]

As far as i can see, this xR thing is obviously a potentiometer, usually, i would do this using superposition, i would firstly find gain when negative port of v1 is on the ground with positive one being connected to generator, and then i would do the other way around, sum of those gains would be the total gain.

However, i am not very familiar with potentiometers in circuit analysis, so i cannot progress any further since i don't know how would circuit equivalent to this look like because solving circuit with arrow pointing towards resistor makes no sense to me. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Replace the potentiometer with a single resistor (call it R2) between the upper node and lower node.

Comment: Ok, and what then, how am i supposed to use parametar x in that case, and why should i replace it with single resistor anyway, why not two or three or something?

Comment: Start calculation (as recommeded by Andy aka) with R2 - and, finally, set R2=(1-x)R. Note that 0<x<=1.

Comment: Why R2=(1-x)R? I must repeat that i am not very familiar with potentiometers in circuit analysis.

Answer (score 1):

**Potentiometer-Resistors Equivalent**

To better explain how to proceed with an answer, one must understand how a potentiometer equivalent can be given by two resistors. In the circuit below, a potentiometer of total resistance R is redrawn as two resistors R1 and R2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkjUVF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This equivalent circuit is valid as long as \$R = R1+R2\$. Let's assume it is a linear potentiometer. This means that, when the wiper (node B):

- is turned "all the way to the left" (the wiper is at A), then \$R1 = 0\$ and \$R2 = R\$;
- is turned "all the way to the right" (the wiper is at C), then \$R1 = R\$ and \$R2 = 0\$;
- is anywhere in between A and C, R1 and R2 increase and decrease linearly with wiper position. When the wiper is at the exact half-point of the potentiometer, then \$R1=R2=R/2\$.

When you connect the wiper to one of the extremes, then it is the same as shorting out one of the resistors in the equivalent. If the wiper is connected to terminal C:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ94vt.png)</sup>

In this equivalent, \$R2\$ can be ignored because it is shorted out and the equivalent resistance between nodes B and C is zero. Therefore, the potentiometer equivalent is just a resistor \$R1\$, that can assume any value in the range 0 (the wiper is at A) to \$R\$ (the wiper is at C).

**How to Proceed with the Exercise in Question**

As can be seen, the wiper is connected to one of the extremities of the potentiometer. Perform the analysis by replacing the potentiometer with a resistor of unknown value \$xR\$. Since, as explained above, \$xR \in [0,R]\$, then it follows that \$x \in [0,1]\$.

Not delving deeper into the circuit itself, as this seems to be homework.

Comment: Vicente Cunha - did you realize that in the given circuit the resistor xR is the part of the potentiometer that is shunted with a short? Therefore the remaining (active) part is (1-x)R.

Comment: @LvW if this is what is intended by writing xR in the "inside" part of the short, then you are correct. But I wouldn't consider it a standard notation practice. Explicitly writing the part that should be ignored next to the wiper makes little sense to my eyes. Still, the overall answer would still be correct, just perform a change of variables.

Comment: OK - I agree. There are two ways to read the drawing.

Comment: Ok, thanks guys, ive tried to solve this using superposition but i messed up badly and could not get out of it, however, i dont know if i can consider currents through R on the inverting input and through R on non-inverting input the same? That would simplify my work significantly.